# How to use a localized string inside a static method

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have to use a translated string into a static method, but it doesn't let me use the keyword 'this'.

My code is something like the following:

```
public static async Task<string> UtilityMethod(){

[...]

this.resourceLoader.GetString("LocalizedString")

[...]

}
```

How can I do?

Comment: Well, you can't use 'this' in any static method, since there is no 'this'. That's how static methods are.

Comment: so how can I call the resourceloader?

Comment: Pass `resourceLoader` as parameter, or store it in `static` field.

Comment: What is the `resourceLoader` declaration?

Comment: private readonly ResourceLoader resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Resources");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't use non-static properties (or fields) in a static method.

As a workaround you can make your resourceLoader also static, or modify the UtilityMethod to have a parameter, so to give you code:

```
private static readonly ResourceLoader resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("Resources");
```

Or:

```
public static async Task<string> UtilityMethod(ResourceLoader resourceLoader){

[...]

resourceLoader.GetString("LocalizedString")

[...]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all **this** keyword is not allowed to be used in the static method.
Reason behind is when you make the method **static** the method is nomore visible to the instance created of the **Class**.

```
public class DemoClass
{
    public int value1 {get;set;}
    public int value2 {get;set;}

    //if you see the below I am using this
    public void method1()
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("value1: {0} value2: {1}", this.value1, this.value1));
    }
    public static void method2()
    { 
     //I callnot access my properties it self :(
     //and cannot be accesed
    }
```

**Useing the extension method to the string class or by overriding the toString() method to translate the string**

Extension Methods http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

Override the ToString [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173154(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173154%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)